# How do I do 2D z-index parallax in Unity3d?

Tags: unity, 2d, parallax-scrolling, draw-order

I am new to unity3d and want to develop a simple game like crazy cabie. I have to implement a z-index parallax for moving sprites towards the player and generating new sprite at the farthest z-index.

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to use the sortingLayer of the sprite renderer and multiply it by a large number such as 1000 for accuracy... When placing the pivot point in your sprite, make it at the very base of the coloured part of the sprite... Done... Unity actually have a tutorial on YouTube about this.

Comment: @Savlon can u provide me link for the tutorial?

Comment: Yeh mate here is the link http://youtu.be/rMCLWt1DuqI